# Пробелы перед выводимыми элементами

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, как убрать пробелы, которые стоят в начале всех элементов, которые идут после первого? В ручную не вариант)

Comment: выглядит как [проблема XY](https://tproger.ru/explain/xyproblem/)

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужен перевод строки после каждого элемента, то лучше его вынести в параметр `sep=`:

```py
print('a', 'b', 'c', sep = '\n')
```

Собственно, пробел, который вы видите между печатаемыми элементами - это значение параметра `sep=` по-умолчанию.

Answer (score 2):

```
print('a\n','b\n','c\n', sep = '')
```

[где я мог про это узнать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Answer (score 0):

Еще пара вариантов

```py
print(f"a\nb\nc\n")
print('a\n'+'b\n'+'c\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Короче есть куча вариантов:
Первый:

```
print('vr\ng\nvcjbmhv\n')
```

Второй:

```
print('vr\n', 'g\n', 'vcjbmhv\n', sep='')
```

Третий:

```
print('vr')
print('g')
print('vcjbmhv')
```